# 413 request entity too large and server error 500

Tags: python, django, nginx, deployment, digital-ocean

I deployed my Django website and everything is fine, but when I tried to upload a profile picture I got

**413 request entity too large nginx 1.18.0(ubuntu)**

this error appear after I turned

```
DEBUG = True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True
```

Then after that I tried to solve that by specifying this

first I opened

```
nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

second I put this in the http

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

and last I restart the nginx by using

```
systemctl restart nginx
```

this actually fixed that 413 error but I faced another one which is

**server error (500)**

**this the logs**

```
2023/07/19 13:38:01 [emerg] 97161#97161: invalid number of arguments in "client_max_body_size" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:17
2023/07/19 13:38:53 [emerg] 97174#97174: invalid number of arguments in "client_max_body_size" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:17
2023/07/19 13:40:26 [emerg] 97196#97196: invalid number of arguments in "client_max_body_size" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:17
2023/07/19 13:44:40 [emerg] 97232#97232: invalid number of arguments in "client_max_body_size" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:17
2023/07/19 13:46:33 [emerg] 97255#97255: invalid number of arguments in "client_max_body_size" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:17
2023/07/19 13:48:09 [emerg] 97279#97279: invalid number of arguments in "client_max_body_size" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:17
2023/07/19 13:50:20 [emerg] 97307#97307: invalid number of arguments in "client_max_body_size" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:17
2023/07/19 13:50:53 [emerg] 97320#97320: invalid number of arguments in "client_max_body_size" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:17
2023/07/19 14:41:42 [alert] 97415#97415: *89 open socket #10 left in connection 5
2023/07/19 14:41:42 [alert] 97415#97415: aborting
2023/07/19 17:05:24 [notice] 99619#99619: signal process started
2023/07/19 17:05:43 [error] 99620#99620: *27 client intended to send too large body: 172006 bytes, client: 105.67.128.42, server: 146.190.58.82>2023/07/19 17:06:50 [notice] 99639#99639: signal process started
2023/07/19 17:08:23 [notice] 99664#99664: signal process started
2023/07/19 17:10:10 [notice] 99691#99691: signal process started
2023/07/19 17:10:18 [error] 99692#99692: *48 client intended to send too large body: 172006 bytes, client: 105.67.128.42, server: 146.190.58.82>2023/07/19 17:13:53 [notice] 99733#99733: signal process started
```

I really don't know what should I do with this. I tried a lot of things but it didn't work please someone coz I'm stuck here

Comment: Please add the nginx error logs or the debug error page to determine why there is an error 500. Also your nginx version is already 2 years eol: https://endoflife.date/nginx

Comment: I added the nginx logs

Comment: The m should be lowercase, not sure if that fixes 100%

Comment: I already changed to lower but it didn't work

Comment: this what I found in the log

Comment: 2023/07/20 07:14:29 [error] 101091#101091: *243 open() "/home/rachwabold/rach/static/admin/javascript/hetong.js" failed (2: No such file or dir>2023/07/20 11:22:34 [notice] 127875#127875: using inherited sockets from "6;"
2023/07/20 11:22:36 [notice] 128099#128099: signal process started